# Python Stream Decode Base64 to valid utf8

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests, base64

I'm currently working on a problem, which I just cannot seem to find the proper solution. Maybe you guys can help me, thanks!

### What I am trying to do

- Web is returning a JSON (value is encoded in valid `BASE64`, which was before that `ùtf-8`)

  - `requests.get(url, stream=True`
- streaming from requests (chunks=1020)

  - `iter_content(chunk_size=1020, decode_unicode=False)`
- do some chunk work (replacing everything with a regex that is not base64)
- add padding if `chunk%4!=0`
- decoding each `Base64`chunk

  - `base64.b64decode(lines_prepared_after_stream).decode('utf-8')`
- write decoded utf8 into a file
  But this does not seem to work. The decoding works but does not deliver correct `utf-8` chunk-wise such that I cannot write it into a file properly.

Any Ideas where my thoughts went wrong?

Example Data (my case was this data but just multiples txt file size):
JSON base64:

```
{
"blob":"bmFtCnRvbQpzYXJhaAp0aW0KbmltCmJpbQpzdmVuCm1vbmlrYQpjaHJpcwpibGEKYmx1Ygpib20Kc2Rmc2Rmc2RkYXNkYXNkYXM="
}
```

Txt file:

```
nam
tom
sarah
tim
nim
bim
sven
monika
chris
bla
blub
bom
sdfsdfsddasdasdas
```

### Code (shortened and skipped, but something along this)

```py
def stream_decode_write(document_ids, client: requests.Session, chunk_size=1024):
   f = open(os.path.join(constants.DEFAULT_DATA_UPLOAD_DIR, document_id), 
           "wb")
   r = client.get(document_url, stream=True, verify=False)
        for lines in r.iter_content(chunk_size, decode_unicode=True):
            # filter keep-alive
            if lines:
                lines = replace_json_input(lines)
                missing_padding = len(lines) % 4
                if missing_padding:
                    lines += '=' * (4 - missing_padding)
                decoded = base64.b64decode(lines.strip()).decode('utf-8)
                f.write(decoded)
```

code i use to encode

```py
def encode_to_base64(file_to_encode) -> str:
    byte_coding = file_to_encode.encode()
    data = base64.b64encode(byte_coding)
    return data.decode('ascii')

def read_from_file(file_path):
    f = open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    return f.read()
```

- first read, then encode, then upload as json

I am guessing that some chunks need some bytes to be prefixed/after to be proper `utf-8`. Maybe I need some kind of this, but I am just unsure though. 
Or Iam dividing the Information to chunks on the wrong places, where actually information continuation is needed..

I looked into this one: [Validate that a stream of bytes is valid UTF-8 (or other encoding) without copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865565/validate-that-a-stream-of-bytes-is-valid-utf-8-or-other-encoding-without-copy)
without success.

Maybe useful:
I do have the might about the file encoding.
Currently I am loading the file into memory and just encode it, put into utf8 and send it upstream per json.

#### Example

base encoded:

```
"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"
```

part which is not decodable:

```
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
```

even if i add padding

LOG output:

```
2019-04-03 10:51:26,549 - chunk_size: 1024
2019-04-03 10:51:26,549 - before replace: {"blob":"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
2019-04-03 10:51:26,549 - replaced chunk : 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
2019-04-03 10:51:26,549 - chunk_size after change: 1015
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example of data that isn't been parsed correctly?

Comment: @dan04 i added some examples and code which i've used/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution I finally used with the help from Mark and a colleague

Because I am streaming I cannot ensure that every byte I receive is a proper multibyte Unicode. Thus it can happen, that decoding fails. As @mark already has mentioned. With this in mind, I have worked on another solution.

As it seems, the decoder makes sure if the received data is a multibyte Unicode it will fail, if the chunk will not be complete.

```
data = '我去过上海。'
```

Let's say this is 5 bytes, but I only receive 4 bytes.

```
decoded = base64.b64decode(data). Decode('utf-8')
```

will fail. thus I probably need a byte from the next chunk. I can wrap this in a except block and try again.
This greedy algorithm should hopefully work if it is not multibyte it can decode it. If it is multibyte it will fail and greedy until it can decode it.

```
prev_chunk.append(current_chunk.pop(0))
```

I need to repeat this action until I either receive proper decoded UTF-8 or my `prev_chunk` and `current_chunk` leads byte-wise combined to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the base64 decoded data binary, because the chunks could break between a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Here's a contrived example.  Original data is UTF-8 broken into chunks and put into a dictionary as the base64-encoded value of a `'blob'` key.  Note the Chinese input used is three bytes per character when encoded in UTF-8, so the chunk size of 5 will break up bytes for one character between chunks.  Then the JSON data is read, the blob decoded and the binary chunks written to a file.  The file is decode as UTF-8 once it is complete.

```
#!coding=utf8
import json
import base64

def test_input():
    '''Test function that returns JSON base64 blobs from
       encoded from five bytes at a time.
    '''
    chunk = 5
    data = '我去过上海。'.encode('utf8')
    for i in range(0,len(data),chunk):
        yield json.dumps({'blob':base64.b64encode(data[i:i+chunk]).decode('ascii')})

with open('output.txt','wb') as f:
    for chunk in test_input():
        print(chunk)
        # decode and add each binary result to a file.
        parsed = json.loads(chunk)
        decoded = base64.b64decode(parsed['blob'])
        f.write(decoded)

# Read in the resulting file as UTF-8 and display
with open('output.txt',encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
{"blob": "5oiR5Y4="}
{"blob": "u+i/h+Q="}
{"blob": "uIrmtbc="}
{"blob": "44CC"}
我去过上海。
```

Comment: Do I have to ensure while encoding that I do that chunk wise as well?
Right now I am just loading everything up too 'n' MB in memory and encoding it.
If I do this, do I have to choose the same amount of chunks while reading?

Comment: I was actually planning not to put every chunk while encoding In a own json key value, but just put everything into on key. The blob.
Such that the blob can range from 1mb to 100 MB in size

Comment: @nmanh Show what you want to do with a working [mcve] and I can give a more targeted answer.  But the key is don't decode the result until you have the complete result.  If you encode in chunks and decode in chunks, you have to be careful to break the chunks on valid boundaries.  That's pretty easy to do with UTF-8, since there is a clear definition of a lead byte, or just use `open(inputfile,'r',encoding='utf8')` and read it with `.read(chunk)`.  It will only return fully decoded text, which you can then `.encode('utf8')` and `base64.b64encode()`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me though! So I added the explicit base64 I am using. What I changed now, according to your answer is just to base64.decode() the chunk and write the bytes into a file, with open ('wb'), which should contain all the bytes of the file b4 uploading. Which then my reader should be able to interpret.

I have updated my answer, which should provide a working mvp

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar, but not quite the same. I thought I'd drop the code here in case anyone might find it useful.

This provides a function which will accept an iterable of chunks (for example streaming [`requests.Request.iter_content`](https://tedboy.github.io/requests/generated/generated/requests.Response.iter_content.html)) and return a stream of decoded bytes.

This needs to operate on the raw bytes and leaves any decoding of the final stream to the caller.

```py
def decode_base64_stream(b64_stream):
    """Get a stream of decoded bytes from an iterable of base 64 bytes."""

    unprocessed = b""

    for chunk in b64_stream:
        # Take a chunk, but remove new lines which aren't part of the b64 data
        unprocessed += chunk.replace(b"\n", b"")

        # Every 4 bytes of Base 64 encode 3 octets exactly; any more or less
        # will potentially encode a partial octet. Therefore, we need to split
        # on exactly 4 bytes:
        # +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
        # |    T      |     W     |     F     |     u     | 4 bytes of 64 input
        # |0 1 0 0 1 1|0 1|0 1 1 0|0 0 0 1|0 1|1 0 1 1 1 0|
        # |       M       |       a       |       n       | 3 output octets
        # +---------------+---------------+---------------+
        safe_len = 4 * (len(unprocessed) // 4)

        # We'll take that many off of the front of the unprocessed bytes
        to_process, unprocessed = unprocessed[:safe_len], unprocessed[safe_len:]

        # It could be we got a very small chunk, and there aren't enough bytes
        # to process
        if to_process:
            yield base64.b64decode(to_process)

    # Clear up any remaining and add extra padding to ensure we can decode
    # regardless of the length. The b64 module doesn't care if there is too
    # much padding, but it might care about too little
    if unprocessed:
        yield base64.b64decode(unprocessed + b"====")
```